# How much / far does this apply?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality-in-context

> "How far is Natural semantic metalanguage really natural?"
>
> "How much is Natural semantic metalanguage really natural?"

Can I use any of these sentences to express: 
**"To what extent is Natural semantic metalanguage really natural?"**

Comment: Neither is idiomatic.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you mean just:
**"How natural is Natural semantic metalanguage?"**

Comment: +1 for suggesting a perfectly idiomatic phrasing.

Comment: Nice.  Although for clarity I would either put quotes around or italicize the first "natural".